# How many way can we obtain $0$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You are walking in road and you have only two directions,forward and back.Your $n$th step has length $n$.

How many way can you return your starting point after $n$ steps ?

It is equivalent to say that we have integers from $1$ to $n$.We want to get $0$ by adding or substructing these numbers.

Let say $a_n$ is the answer.We can say that $a_1=0$ and $a_2=0$ as it is impossible to get $0$ and $a_3=2$ since $$1+2-3=0$$ $$-1-2+3=0$$

I can show that $a_n$ is nonzero if $n\equiv0 mod(4)$,but I am not even near to find $a_n$.

Any result about $a_n$ would be appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence you're interested in is [A063865](http://oeis.org/A063865) on OEIS.  On the linked page you will find that $a_n=0$ unless $n\equiv 0,3\pmod 4$.  You'll also find a generating function for $a_n$ and an asymptotic behavior, which was proved in a 2013 paper of B.D. Sullivan.

Comment: Ther is an asymptotic formula in your link,does it means that it has no closed proper formula(: $a(n) \backsim sqrt(6/Pi)n^(-3/2)2^n for n = 0 or 3 (mod 4)$ )

Comment: @mesel: Yes.  If a closed form were known, OEIS would likely have it posted.  The generating function though gives a fairly efficient way of computing $a_n$ for small enough values of $n$.  Notice the link which computes values through $n=400$.

Answer (score 1):

The total length of your steps is $\frac 12n(n+1)$  You need this to be even, so you need $n$ or $n+1$ to be a multiple of $4$  To show you can always do it in those cases, add numbers from the top until the sum is too large, then reduce the last one to make the correct sum.

Comment: Can you find $a_n$ in that case?